# Why is the $Z(G)$ is subgroup pre-image of $Z(G/Z(G))$ under the natural projection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $\pi$ is the natural projection of $G$ onto $G/Z(G)$, i.e

$\pi\ :\ G \rightarrow G/Z(G)$, where $g \mapsto gZ(G)$. Can someone explain to me why is $Z(G) \leq \pi^{-1}({Z(G/Z(G))})$ ?  I need to understand this in order to understand nilpotent groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\colon G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism; then, for every subgroup $H'$ of $G'$,
$$
f^{-1}(H')\supseteq \ker f
$$
just because $1\in H'$.

Apply to $f=\pi$, whereby $\ker f=Z(G)$, and $H'=Z(G/Z(G))$.

Comment: Nice, indeed the more general point of view here. +1

Comment: very very very good

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the image of any element of $Z(G)$ under the projection map $\pi$ is the identity coset $eZ(G)$.